# Denzel's Russian in "The Equalizer"

Tags: dialogue, the-equalizer

Can anyone tell me what **Denzel** says to the **Russian mobster (at 33:11)**, after shoving the **corkscrew** through his lower jaw up to his mouth, and after counting "1/1000"?

He says something which I suspect is Russian, and probably something sarcastic/cynical (or maybe just something like "bye sucker", but I'm guessing).

Comment: Hi, Welcome to MTV SE. Screenshot would be much more helpful on this, but meanwhile try reading the script [here](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=the-equalizer)

Answer (score 2):

He says "eight one-thousand" (counting to himself) and then...

> "Understand".

[image]

The "understand" is a callback to what the same villain said to Robert when they picked up Alina of the street on her walk with Robert earlier in the movie.

> "Don't be shy. Make the call. Understand?"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like we were both right: it was spoken in Russian, but it does translate as "understand".